# Error: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: angularjs, node.js, methods

I'm facing an issue and would like your help, please.
I'm setting a portion of code that goes to a folder and deletes a file from a list, on the front page, but also in the file system.
Problem is, when i'm performing an action, i'm getting an error in the browser's console : 500 Internal Server Error.
When i'm looking at the REQUEST URL, it appears that the path seems right but stops at /deleteFile/ and doesn't reach the file's name.

Angular Code

```
$scope.deleteFile = (idx) ->
      console.log($scope.fileList)
      file = $scope.fileList[idx]
      Theme.deleteFile {name: file.name}
      .$promise.then (response) ->
        if (response.status is 200)
          $scope.fileList.splice(idx, 1)
        else
        $scope.fileList.splice(idx, 1)
```

Deleting function and remote method

```
Theme.deleteFile = (name, next) ->
    fs.unlink('/applis/tnuv/www/vizir/uploads/' + name, (err)) ->
      if err
        console.log 'Deletion failed'
      else
        console.log 'Successfully deleted'
      next()

  Theme.remoteMethod 'deleteFile',
  accepts: [
    { arg: 'name', type: 'string', required: true, http: {source: 'path'} }
  ]
  http:
    verb: 'delete'
    path: 'deleteFile/:name'
```

Jade code

```
md-subheader.md-no-sticky(ng-show="fileList.length" layout="row" layout-align="center center" style="background-color:#ff5252; color:#000000") Uploaded files
md-list-item.make-scrollable(ng-repeat='item in fileList')
  p
    a(href="")  {{ item }} 
  p Document
  p Success
  md-button.md-icon-button.md-primary.md-hue-0.limitElipsis.a.deleteHandle(ng-click="deleteFile($index)")
    md-icon(md-menu-origin md-svg-icon="trash")
```

Comment: `Http Status code 500 - Internal Server Error` - *"A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable"* - This almost always originates from the server. You have to debug the server side code (ie. the node.js code) to figure out why the error occurred. It is usually caused by an unhandled exception, attach the debugger or wrap the code in a try/catch and see what the exception is.

Comment: The error i'm actually getting from the terminal is error: invalid input syntax for integer: "deleteFile"

Comment: You should update your question with that error, do not provide it as a comment.